# What is the Roll20 syntax needed to add a +1 bonus from the Weapon Focus feat to an attack with a long arm?

Tags: starfinder, roll20

Under Weapon & Armor Proficiencies > Attacks:
I am trying to add a bonus +1 to my attack with a long arm because of the Weapon Focus feat (1st level soldier).  I tried:

```
Attack Roll [DEX] + 2 [+1 insight to attack]
```

The [+1 insight to attack] does not seem to add 1 to my attack roll.  Is there another way?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Are you using the Starfinder Official sheet by Roll20?

Answer (score 2):

#### Either remove the non-numeric text, or use inline labels.

The expression "`+1 insight to attack`" is not valid for [Roll20 roll syntax](https://wiki.roll20.net/Dice_Reference#How_to_Roll_Dice).  The "`+1`" can be parsed as a +1 increased value, but the "`insight to attack`" substring is not evaluated.

To include non-numeric text in the rolls, enclose that text in paired single brackets. This notation is for [inline labels](https://wiki.roll20.net/Dice_Reference#Inline_Labels), which are like tooltip comments that appear when you hover your cursor over the roll output. To add the +1 as a bonus to the roll, you need the numeric parts to be outside the paired brackets, and the non-numeric text in between the paired brackets.

For example, if you're using the Starfinder template for Roll20 character sheets, then you could fill in the text as "`+1[insight]`". This substring is then incorporated in the roll macro.

[image]

This notation should add the +1 to your attack rolls. When you hover the cursor over your attack rolls in the chat area, the text "insight" should be visible in the equation.